# accelerated HTML5 video: what hardware is supported well by Linux?

Tags: debian, hardware, video, browser, gpu

After many, many, many failed attempts to get accelerated HTML5 video working on *any* hardware (tested about 5 machines) I came to the conclusion that accelerated HTML5 is something difficult under Linux.

Now I "just" need some hardware to realize a HTML5/WebRTC based (not only) video conferencing application for use with a TV, but I don't know where to find suitable hardware. It's all easier with Windows, but I'd like to stick with Linux for other reasons.

Can somebody tell me *how to find* or suggest some hardware that will...

- be supported by some HTML5 browser **with WebRTC support** (video conferencing) - preferably Chrome/Chromium
- allow fluid video playback up to HD resolutions
- may be Intel architecture (preferred) or also ARM if there is some open board support package
- have HDMI output
- under Debian Jessie, or perhaps Ubuntu
- preferably with X11, but it's not important as only the (headless) browser is displayed full-screen (HTML5 application)

It would also be a great help if it boils down to *"graphics card X works well with Chrome if you use Kernel X"*.

I know that I'm asking for *hardware* but it's actually Linux software that's heavily limiting the selection, so I assume this is not off-topic.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean you need to activate html5 on navigateur under linux?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. We want to create sort of a set-top-box for a TV. For reasons of fast application development that set-top-box should run Linux (we already use a customized Debian Linux for a variety of projects) and run continuously an interactive HTML5 application (paired with a NodeJS server on the same device), that has yet to be created. Among other things, that HTML5 application must be able to run a WebRTC video conference, as that is a key part of the project. .. and of course a browser is required to display the HTML5 application.

Comment: Can you describe further how you have determined that it failed? I am using Intel chipsets, AMD and sometimes NVidia on very old hardware with great results playing HD video (1080pp, H264). How are you testing for HTML5/WebRTC "support"?

Comment: How is your HTML5 video encoded? If VP9, there is no full hardware supporting full acceleration for it yet (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563206#c39). Knowing how you test/app(s) used, more details on codecs used and expected results would help a lot.

Comment: @MagicFab: for a quick test, just try to play a full HD YouTube video in Chrome (does it run smoothly), and ultimately run a full-screen video chat and check latency/frame rate. Chrome also shows if hw-accelerated video is available on it's [chrome://gpu/](chrome://gpu/) page. For example, there is a *standalone* hw-accelerated video player for the Raspberry Pi, but Chrome can't use the GPU for video playback.

Comment: @MagicFab, regarding codecs: None in particular. Just running a WebRTC video chat and letting the browser negotiate the codecs. If choosing a particular codec helps, that's fine. I don't have any preference.. FYI, a simple test is using the free video chat service offered by [appear.in](https://appear.in/)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying.

Re: OpenGL, acceleration and the Raspberry Pi, I found [one report of it working with Raspbian](https://www.scirra.com/blog/ashley/23/how-to-get-webgl-on-the-raspberry-pi-2), a dedicated distribution, unsing Chromium.

I used the tests mentioned there and they [run at 60 FPS](https://www.scirra.com/demos/c2/sbperftest/), or just look/feel smooth and report hardware acceleration with Chromium - without any custom changes or configuration.

I have too many restrictions in Firefox (ex-IceWeasel, version 45) in Debian testing so couldn't verify it there. This is a stock 4.4 kernel, no tweaking in drivers, Intel chipset + free drivers.

The [Hello Racer demo](http://helloracer.com/webgl/) also ran smoothly, this a Thinkpad X230 running Debian Testing. I'd say Chromium should work fine on any Intel-based hardware dating back ~4y or less.

Answer (score 0):

If you read this bugtracker entry https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563206 and you give up all hope. Opened 2010 and it is still being discussed how and when this would be integrated.

Unfortunately Linux has not the same standardized approach to APIs, probably because there were no stakeholders at the time who were negotiating this with graphic card vendors. Windows and probably iOS are still much more advanced regarding consumer technology.